# PHP - is there a way to use an xml attribute and transform it into a php variable?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML which is made in this way:

```
<marketstat>
 <type id="17889">
  <buy>
   <volume>15005046</volume>
   <avg>704.84</avg>
   <max>755.88</max>
   <min>428.10</min>
   <stddev>58.87</stddev>
   <median>753.77</median>
   <percentile>755.87</percentile>
  </buy>
  <sell>
   <volume>43601243</volume>
   <avg>1017.32</avg>
   <max>1697.90</max>
   <min>917.94</min>
   <stddev>190.56</stddev>
   <median>953.01</median>
   <percentile>917.94</percentile>
  </sell>
 </type>
 <type id="44">
  <buy>
   <volume>15005046</volume>
   <avg>704.84</avg>
   <max>755.88</max>
   <min>428.10</min>
   <stddev>58.87</stddev>
   <median>753.77</median>
   <percentile>755.87</percentile>
  </buy>
  <sell>
   <volume>43601243</volume>
   <avg>1017.32</avg>
   <max>1697.90</max>
   <min>17.9</min>
   <stddev>190.56</stddev>
   <median>953.01</median>
   <percentile>917.94</percentile>
  </sell>
 </type>
</marketstat>
```

Is there a way i can take the attribute id inside the tag type and transform it in a php variable with the same name giving it a value inside the xml?

What i am aiming is to have a variable for every id and assign the value of the sell->min inside the xml so that after i can call it to make some calculations.

Something like:

```
$17889 = "917.94";
$44 = "17.9";
```

or the only thing i can do is using the $xml->xpath('//marketstat/type[@id="17889"]/sell/min'); each time i want to get the value of it?

Comment: I just updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. It is possible, but it is not possible to have a variable like '$17889' as variable names must start with a letter or an underscore. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Now if you want something like `$_17889 = "917.94";` and `$_44 = "17.9";`, so with an underscore in front of the id, you can do something like:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//marketstat/type');
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    $attr = $node->attributes();
    $id = "_" . $attr['id'];
    $$id = $node->sell[0]->min[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your suggestion nl-x i've been able to solved this riddle.

I have just "hacked" your code in something i feel more confortable to use, a normal foreach cycle loop

```
foreach ($xml->marketstat->type as $type)
        {
        $typeid = $type[id];
        $id = "_" . $typeid;
        $$id = $type->sell->min;
        }
```

thanks o much again.

Comment: You need to change `[id]` into `['id']`. Otherwise it might throw notices.